# Emulating Arrays and Looping with Apache SSI

Tags: apache, ssi

I want to declare a variable that is capable of holding multiple values in Apache SSI. Then I want to iterate over the values and print them on the page.

Could I do that using regular expressions and recursive includes? Am I crazy, or could I make this work:

In index.html

```
<!--#set var="values" value="a,b,c" -->
<!--#set var="count" value="0" -->

<ul>
    <!--#include virtual="looper.shtml" -->
</ul>
```

in looper.shtml:

```
<!-- I need some sort of terminal condition -->
<!--#set var="value" value="use a regexp to get the value at values[count] (not sure how)" -->
<!--#set var="count" value="count + 1 (not sure how to do that either)" -->

<li><!--#echo var="value" --></li>

<!--#include virtual="looper.shtml" -->
```

Comment: While I am a huge fan of abusing tools for entertainment purposes, surely you could just throw together a short script to do this with the same (or less!) amount of effort?

Comment: Yeah I could just do a perl script but it would be a hassle to convince the webmaster to turn on exec-cgi privliges.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RewriteRule` and `RewriteMap` to concatenate values into a variable and print values respectively:

```
#Redirect a URI to an all-lowercase version of itself

RewriteMap lc int:tolower 
RewriteRule (.*[A-Z]+.*) ${lc:$1} [R]
```

**References**

- [Advanced Techniques with mod_rewrite - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.5](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/advanced.html)
- [Can I concatenate environment variables in apache config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397090/can-i-concatenate-environment-variables-in-apache-config/11270519#11270519)
- [Apache RewriteRule with RewriteMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909438/apache-rewriterule-with-rewritemap)
- [Using RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewritemap.html#int)
- [RewriteMap in Action](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/apache/2005/04/28/apacheckbk.html)